# Create Spark Dataframe from existing Dataframe such that new Dataframe's columns based on existing Dataframe rows

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have existing dataframe as:

```
Timestamp,         ID,   Value
29/08/2017 4:51:23, ID-1, 1.1
29/08/2017 4:52:14, ID-2, 2.1
29/08/2017 4:52:14, ID-3, 3.1
29/08/2017 4:55:23, ID-1, 1.2
29/08/2017 4:55:23, ID-3, 3.2
29/08/2017 4:57:42, ID-2, 2.2
```

I would like to create a dataframe from existing dataframe such that 'IDs' will become column names and 'Values' will become the data of respective columns as:

```
Timestamp,            ID-1,    ID-2,   ID-3
29/08/2017 4:51:23,    1.1,     null,   null
29/08/2017 4:52:14,    null,    2.1,    3.1
29/08/2017 4:55:23,    1.2,     null,   3.2
29/08/2017 4:57:42,    null,    2.2,    null
```

I am not able to figure out feasible solution for this in Scala. Help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `groupBy()` together with `piviot()`. Using your example dataframe:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._

val df = ...

df.show()
+------------------+----+-----+
|         Timestamp|  ID|Value|
+------------------+----+-----+
|29/08/2017 4:51:23|ID-1|  1.1|
|29/08/2017 4:52:14|ID-2|  2.1|
|29/08/2017 4:52:14|ID-3|  3.1|
|29/08/2017 4:55:23|ID-1|  1.2|
|29/08/2017 4:55:23|ID-3|  3.2|
|29/08/2017 4:57:42|ID-2|  2.2|
+------------------+----+-----+

val newDF = df.groupBy("Timestamp")
  .pivot("ID")
  .agg(sum($"Value"))

newDF.show()
+------------------+----+----+----+
|         Timestamp|ID-1|ID-2|ID-3|
+------------------+----+----+----+
|29/08/2017 4:57:42|null| 2.2|null|
|29/08/2017 4:55:23| 1.2|null| 3.2|
|29/08/2017 4:51:23| 1.1|null|null|
|29/08/2017 4:52:14|null| 2.1| 3.1|
+------------------+----+----+----+
```

If the timestamp and id is the same for two or more rows, those values will be added together. If you want another behavior simply change the `agg()` method. E.g. average would be `agg(avg($"Value"))`.

Hope it helps!